# 'str' object has no attribute 'csrf_exempt' while returning response from a django view?

Tags: python, django, django-nonrel, gunicorn

I have this strange problem with my view which is returning response in json format.My view looks like this:

```
def CheckPlayer(request,client_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(id = client_id)
        except:
            return Error(message = "User doesnot exists.")
        message = request.GET.get('message','')
        if not message:
            return Error(message = "Argument Missing.")
        response = {}
        result = MakingRequest(message)
        result = json.loads(result)
        if result['failure'] == '0':
            response['failure'] = '0'
        else:
            response['failure'] = '1'
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), mimetype="application/javascript")
    else:
        return Error()


def MakingRequest(message):
    values = {'message':message}
    rObjects =  Ram.objects.all()
    temp = []
    for i in rObjects:
        temp.append(i.appId)
    values['registration_ids'] = temp
    param = json.dumps(values)
    req = urllib2.Request("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send", param)
    req.add_header( 'Content-Type' , 'application/json' )
    req.add_header( 'Authorization' , 'key=7FcEMnl0FRTSBjhfjfhjfHi1Rmg04Ns' )
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    return response.read()
```

I have tested it on my local server it works perfectly , but if I run it on my server (nginx,gunicorn,django-mongoDB,mongoDB) then it gives me this Error.I know about this error that if a view doesnot return HttpResponse from a view then it djangi raises error **"Nonetype object has no attribute csrf_exempt' "** but in my case i am returning response which is in json format but still its giving me error.Please help me

Comment: Not sure what Error() returns. Your production may returns one of your Error() cases and it may return a string, so that could be a problem

Comment: But why is csrf_exempt decorator is even called when I am not using it for this view

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning an HttpResponse when you return Error(), so Django can't apply the decorator to it.